# kubernetes - Nginx, cert-manager, mounted secret file renewal issue

Tags: nginx, ssl, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, cert-manager

The certificate file of cert-manager is mounted on the nginx volume and is being used.

e.g

**nginx deploy.yaml -**

```
  volumes:
    - name: secret-volume
      secret:
        secretName: my.test.app.com
    - name: configmap-volume
      configMap:
        name: nginxconfigmap
  containers:
    - name: nginxhttps
      image: bprashanth/nginxhttps:1.0
      ports:
        - containerPort: 443
        - containerPort: 80
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/nginx/ssl
          name: secret-volume
        - mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
          name: configmap-volume
```

**and my nginx.conf file in**

```
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/tls.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/tls.key;
```

And it's working very well.
In addition, the certificate is smoothly reissued by cert-manager.

However, because the reissued certificate file is not updated in the nginx container, it is said that the certificate has expired when accessed from a browser.

There is no problem if I force restart the pod, but I want to automate it.

I wonder if there is a way to automatically renew the certificate without restarting the pod forcibly.

Comment: Is the assumption that the `YAML` manifest that you've included is not connected to the `nginx-ingress` correct? Please tell on which step the certificate is not being updated (`Secret`, inside of a `Pod`, or `nginx` itself)? According to the documentation`Secret` should be [updated eventually](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#mounted-secrets-are-updated-automatically) if it's mounted as a `Volume`. Also according to [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247460) a reload is necessary for new certs to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure that the certificate is for your specific application using **Nginx** or main `Nginx ingress` which is handing the whole traffic of your cluster.

if it is the main **Nginx** which is handling the whole traffic of your cluster you can create the **ingress** and add the **cert-manager** integration there.

Cert-manager will manage the certificate and save it inside the secret and ingress will use that secret run time. Whenever the certificate gets renew secret content will game update while ingress will be using the same secret name.

in the above scenario there no pod restart required.

if you want to read and check the whole example please refer: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes

in the above example, Nginx will run without having any certificate in volume while it will use the certificate stored in secret.

For YAML example if **issuer** and **ingress** please check : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67184948/5525824

Comment: Thanks for the quick and accurate answer.!!! Was very helpful.

Comment: Glad to hear that you found it helpful and worked you can also upvote the answer.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Stack Overflow site yet, so I forgot! Hahaha
Have a nice day!

Comment: no worries thanks a lot and same to you. have a great day ahead.